# How to run a script only once per day with cron without specifying execution time

Tags: cron

I wan to run a backup script once per day but I don't want to specify a certain time, just once per day. I've read that the @daily cron attribute runs every day at 00:00 but i don't know if the receiving server will be up at this time.

Is it possible to configure `cron` to run this script just once per day irrespective of the time? Or run the script until it succeeds and then try again the next day?

@reboot would be an option however the sending end might reboot several times per day in which case it would lead to unnecessary backups.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may want to use the anacron.

From its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/anacron.8.html)

> ```
> NAME
>        anacron - runs commands periodically
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        anacron [-s] [-f] [-n] [-d] [-q] [-t anacrontab] [-S spooldir] [job] ...
>        anacron [-S spooldir] -u [-t anacrontab] [job] ...
>        anacron [-V|-h]
>        anacron -T [-t anacrontab]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        Anacron  can  be  used  to  execute  commands periodically, with a frequency specified in days.  Unlike
>        cron(8), it does not assume that the machine is  running  continuously.   Hence,  it  can  be  used  on
>        machines  that  aren't running 24 hours a day, to control daily, weekly, and monthly jobs that are usu‐
>        ally controlled by cron.
> ```

The Ubuntu community HowTo: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Using anacron:

1. Simply put the executable script file in the `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` or `/etc/cron.monthly`.
2. Touch the script file:

   ```
   sudo touch /etc/cron.daily/scriptfile
   ```

   (`cron.daily` if it is a daily job).

Testing anacron:

```
sudo anacron -f -d
```

> ```
>    -f     Force execution of the jobs, ignoring the timestamps.
>    -d     Don’t fork to the background.  In this mode, Anacron will output
>           informational  messages to standard error, as well as to syslog.
>           The output of jobs is mailed as usual.
> ```

Anacron messages in the log:

```
grep anacron /var/log/syslog
```

Anacron keeps timestamps in the `/var/spool/anacron/`. If you remove `cron.daily`, `cron.weekly` or `cron.monthly` files from there, anacron will execute daily, weekly or monthly scripts at the next startup.

Comment: So just dumping the scripts in the cron.daily will do the job?

Comment: Wha do you need to touch the script?

Comment: Sometimes, at here, the anacron is not executing the new script. The touch has helped at here.

Answer (score 0):

Use @daily as you are, but add @reboot as well. @reboot will run the script when you boot.

```
@reboot /full_path/to/script
```

See [Ubuntu wiki cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) for additional information.

Comment: Yes but this was I might get multiple executions per day, right?